# systemctl statConnection reset by {ip} port 22

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I have installed Ubuntu 20.10 server (64 bit) on my raspberry-pi 4 and configured ssh connection via wlan0.

I am able to connect to ssh and execute commands but after a while my terminal start getting stuck when I'm writing new command ( Cant see what i am writing). Sometimes after a while it will show what I am writing and I can execute new command but sometimes I can see message:

```
systemctl statConnection reset by 192.168.1.107 port 22
```

and then my connection is closed. After make new connection it's start from beginning.

Does anyone know what it can be? How to fix it?